# Artifactory permissions

Tags: maven, artifactory

I have problems with configurations using Maven + Artifactory.

I try to download a new external file using a user created in Artifactory and my Artifactory doesn´t make download, claiming "Access denied" but if I put the same credentials as defined in remote settings, my application can download every external jars.

If I use the same permission setting of my remote configuration `settings.xml` where the Artifactory was installed (user *admin*) I can make downloads quickly.

There´s some way to configure to create a user in my Artifactory and configure the permission to make downloads of new artefacts? Because I didn´t find in anywhere.

I think that is more secure for my company if I have the possibility to create a new user in my Artifactory and just give the permissions: read and to download new artefacts but this option doesn´t exist in Artifactory.

How could I do this?

Comment: Do you mean that Maven received Access Denied from Artifactory, or does Artifactory receive and Access Denied from a remote repository?

Answer (score 6):

Because you've created a user entity within Artifactory, make sure it's got at least [read permissions](http://wiki.jfrog.org/confluence/display/RTF/Managing+Permissions) on all the repositories you'd like to resolve from.

For easier Maven configuration, you can also use Artifactory to [generate proper Maven settings](http://wiki.jfrog.org/confluence/display/RTF/Configuring+Artifacts+Resolution) for yourself; this helps to reduce typos and reference mistakes (make sure you're logged in as the user entity you've created whilst generating the settings). After applying the settings file you can also run the *mvn help:effective-settings* goal on your project to make sure everything was applied correctly.

Finally, if you're required to authenticate with the remote repository you're proxying, you'll need to he [specify the credentials](http://wiki.jfrog.org/confluence/display/RTF/Advanced+Settings) in the configuration of that remote repository.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure the user you are using to connect to Artifactory has `Deploy` permissions in Artifactory. The `Deploy` permission allows the user to download artifacts from repositories (in other words, populate cache with remote artifacts).

https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/RTF/Managing+Permissions

> **Deploy** Allows deploying artifacts and deploying to caches (i.e.
>   populating caches with remote artifacts)

More information from the JFrog forum:

http://forums.jfrog.org/Maven-using-anonymous-user-even-though-artifactory-server-setup-in-the-settings-xml-td4634521.html